# Why is my Powershell script returing extra output when run by Nagios NRPE?

Tags: powershell, nagios, nrpe

I have a Powershell script that I'm running via nrpe as an external script.  The windows server (2008) is running nsclient++ (nscp.exe) v 0.4.1.102.

The return section of my powershell script looks like this

```
 } else {
                    write-host "ok $queue|queue = $queue"
                    exit 0
 }
```

And the wrapper script to call the ps1 file looks like this:

```
ps1 = cmd /c echo C:\\NetAdmin\\%SCRIPT% %ARGS%; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -
```

If I run this from a windows command prompt the output looks something like:

```
ok 93|queue = 93
```

But when I run is using check_nrpe from my nagios server the output changes to:

```
ok 93|'queue''=0 '93'=0
```

Nagios is having an issue processing the performance data.

UPDATE:
After filing a bug report, the software author replied that this is desired behavior, but that there are two options for disabling it in the nsclient.ini:

Globally (All scripts)

```
[/settings/external scripts/scripts/default]
ignore perfdata = true
```

Single script

```
[/settings/external scripts/scripts/check_foo]
ignore perfdata = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to remove extra spaces around `=` sign :

```
write-host "ok $queue|queue=$queue"
```

By now i cannot explain this behaviour on this version of `nsclient++`. This is not happening on some previous versions like `v0.3.8.76` which works like a charm (at least, as expected without surprises).

Seems that `nsclient++` extends spaces as a data with a value of `0`. It could be a bug or a wanted behaviour.

I am actually searching for some clues on the Internet, and will try to analyse source code.

Comment: This indeed worked.  I may file a bug report today

Comment: @uSlackr Let me know if you file a bug report. post the link ;) Thanks

Comment: Ticket opened here: http://nsclient.org/nscp/ticket/712#ticket

Comment: take a look at the note on this ticket.  Apparently there is a config option to fix the parsing.  I'm planning to add it to my answer once I test it. http://nsclient.org/nscp/ticket/712#ticket

Comment: @uSlackr Yes i saw that this afternoon. Tested it and it worked. I let you update the answer ;) It appears that it was a wanted behaviour and not a bug ! Cheers

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is what nscp does to the data when it parse it.  Is it simply a format verification?